# Problema com relacionamento entre dois SELECT preenchidos com PHP

Tags: php, html, jquery

Olá. (Fiz uma pergunta sobre isso esses dias, mas não consegui obter resultado com as respostas).

Tenho dois selects (que são preenchidos com PHP com dados vindo do banco de dados mysql).

Eu gostaria de quando eu selecionar um valor em um select, o outro select fosse alterado para o valor correspondente.

Exemplo: Tenho um select lista os código das empresas, e outro com as empresas. Eu gostaria de que quando eu selecionasse o código de uma empresa no select, o outro select 'automaticamente' mudasse para a empresa correspondente ao código selecionado.

Eu consegui fazer com que ao selecionar o código, a empresa relacionada a ele fosse selecionada no outro select. Porém não consegui fazer o inverso. Ao selecionar a empresa, o código dela não é selecionado no outro select.

Estou a 4 dias fazendo isso e o pessoal do estágio já estão perdendo um pouco a paciência. Se vocÊs conseguirem me ajudar, ficarei grato.

Segue abaixo o código:

```js
//FUNCAO PARA PRENCHER SELECT EMPRESA DE ACORDO COM O CÓDIGO (COD) ESCOLHIDO

$(function() 
 {

 $("select#codigo-empresa").change(function(e) 
 {
  var cod = $("select#codigo-empresa option:selected").attr('id');
  //$('select#empresa').show('<option selected>' + cod + '</option>');
  $("select#empresa").val(cod);
    
 
  
 });
  
 
});


//FUNCAO PARA PRENCHER SELECT COD DE ACORDO COM A EMPRESA ESCOLHIDA

$(function() 
 {

 $("select#empresa").change(function(e) 
 { 
   
  var codigo = $("select#empresa option:selected").attr('id');
  $("select#codigo-empresa").val(codigo);
  
  
 });
  
 
});





//FUNCAO PARA PRENCHER SELECT TRIBUTAÇÃO DE ACORDO COM O CÓDIGO (COD) ESCOLHIDO

$(function() 
 {
 $("select#codigo-empresa").change(function(e) 
 {
  var trib = $("select#codigo-empresa option:selected").attr('name');
  $("input[id='tributacao']").val(trib);
  
 
 
 });

  
 
});


//FUNCAO PARA PRENCHER SELECT TRIBUTAÇÃO DE ACORDO COM A EMPRESA ESCOLHIDO

$(function() 
 {
 $("select#empresa").change(function(e) 
 {
  var tribu = $("select#empresa option:selected").attr('name');
  $("input[id='tributacao']").val(tribu);
 
  
  
 });

  
 
});
```

```html
<form action="banco-de-dados/tela-atividade-extra/update.php" method="post" id="formulario-login-sistema" onSubmit="alert('Atividade Cadastrada com Sucesso');">
       
       <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
        <label for="colaborador">Colaborador:</label>
        <select name="colaborador" id="colaborador" class="input form-control">
         <option><?php echo utf8_decode($_SESSION["nome"]) ?></option>    
        </select>
        
       </div>
       
       <div class="form-group col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-1">
        <label for="atividade">Qual será a atividade ?</label>
        <select name="atividade" id="atividade" class="input form-control">
         <?php
          while($registros_atividade = $query_pegar_atividades -> fetch_assoc())
          {
         ?> 
          <option id="<?php echo utf8_decode($registros_atividade["ATIVIDADE"]); ?> "> 
           <?php echo  utf8_decode($registros_atividade['ATIVIDADE']); ?>
          </option>

         <?php
          }
         ?>        
        </select>
                  
       </div>
       
            
       
       <!-- LINHA -->
       
       <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
       
        <label for="data-vencimento">Qual é a data de vencimento:</label>
        <input type="date" name="data-vencimento" id="data-vencimento" class="input form-control" value="<?php echo $data_de_hoje_form_atividade; ?>">
        
       </div>
       
       <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1">
        <label for="designou-atividade">Quem designou a atividade?</label>
        <select name="designou-atividade" id="designou-atividade" class="input form-control">
         <option>CLIENTE</option>
         <?php
          while($registros_usuario = $query_pegar_designador -> fetch_assoc())
          {
         ?> 
          <option id="<?php echo utf8_decode($registros_usuario["usuario"]); ?> "> 
           <?php echo  utf8_decode($registros_usuario['usuario']); ?>
          </option>

         <?php
          }
         ?>     
        </select>
        
        
         
       </div>

       <!-- LINHA -->
       
       <div class="col-lg-12 alinhar-texto-no-centro" id="selecionar-empresas">
        <h3 class="alinhar-texto-no-centro">Selecionar Empresa</h3>
              
        <!-- CAMPO CODIGO DA EMPRESA -->
        <div class="form-group col-lg-2">
        
         <label for="codigo-empresa">COD</label>
         <select name="codigo-empresa" id="codigo-empresa" class="input form-control">
         <option></option>
          <?php
           while($registros_cod = $query_pegar_cod -> fetch_assoc())
           {
          ?> 
           <option id="<?php echo utf8_decode($registros_cod['EMPRESAS']);?>" name="<?php echo utf8_decode($registros_cod["TRIBUTACAO"]);?>"> 
            <?php echo  utf8_decode($registros_cod['COD']); ?>
           </option>

          <?php
           }
          ?>  
         </select>
         
        
        </div>
             
        <!-- CAMPO EMPRESA -->
        <div class="form-group col-lg-7">
         <label for="empresa">Empresa</label>
         <select name="empresa" id="empresa" class="input form-control">
         <option></option>
          <?php
          while($registros_empresas = $query_pegar_empresa -> fetch_assoc())
          {
          ?> 
           <option id="<?php echo utf8_decode($registros_empresas['COD']);?> " name="<?php echo utf8_decode($registros_empresas["TRIBUTACAO"]); ?> "> 
            <?php echo  utf8_decode($registros_empresas['EMPRESAS']); ?>
           </option>
                      
          <?php
           }
          ?>      
         </select>
         
         
         
        </div>
        
        <!-- CAMPO TRIBUTAÇÃO -->
        <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
         <label for="tributacao">Tributação</label>
         <input name="tributacao" id="tributacao" class="input form-control" readonly>
          
         </input>
                          
        </div>
        
        
        <!-- CAMPO POSSUIR ARQUIVOS -->
        <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-9" id="lista-empresas" style="display:inline">
         <div class="form-inline">
          <div class="radio">
           <label>
            <input type="radio" name="empresas-filtro" id="empresas-filtro" value="sim" class="form-control" checked>Minhas
           </label>
          </div>
          
          <div class="radio">
           <label>
            <input type="radio" name="empresas-filtro" id="empresas-filtro" value="nao" class="form-control">Todas
           </label>
          </div>
         </div>         
        </div>

        
        
        
       </div>

       <!-- LINHA -->
       
        <!-- CAMPO DETALHES -->
        
        <div class="form-group col-lg-12" id="destalhes">
         <label for="destalhes-da-atividade">Detalhes sobre a atividade</label>
         <textarea class="form-control" name="destalhes-da-atividade" id="destalhes-da-atividade" style="resize:none" maxlength="500" rows="10" placeholder="Descreva detalhes sobre a atividade"></textarea>
        
        </div>

       <!-- LINHA -->

        <!-- CAMPO QUANTIDADE DE PROCESSOS -->
        <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
         <label for="quantidade-processos">Quantidade de Processos: </label>
         <input class="form-control" type="number" name="quantidade-processos" id="quantidade-processos" min="1" max="100" maxlength="40" required>
        </div>
        
        <!-- CAMPO POSSUIR ARQUIVOS -->
        <div class="form-group col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-4" id="possui-arquivo" style="display:inline">
         <label for="possui-arquivo">Possui Arquivo ?</label>
         <div class="form-inline">
          <div class="radio">
           <label>
            <input type="radio" name="possui-arquivo" id="opcao-radio" value="S" class="form-control" checked> SIM
           </label>
          </div>
          
          <div class="radio">
           <label>
            <input type="radio" name="possui-arquivo" id="possui-arquivo" value="N" class="form-control"> NÃO
           </label>
          </div>
         </div>         
        </div>

        
        <!-- LINHA -->
        
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-9 form-group">
         <input name="salvar-atividade-extra" id="salvar-atividade-extra" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Salvar">
        </div>
       
      </form>
            
            
<?php
 
 date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT+3');
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "", "pt_BR.utf-8");
 
 
 $departamento_usuario = $_SESSION["departamento-usuario"];
 $usuario_logado = $_SESSION["nome"];
 
 
 $create_one = "select distinct ATIVIDADE from Tbl_Atividades_Por_Dep where DEPARTAMENTO = '{$departamento_usuario}'";
 $query_pegar_atividades =  mysqli_query($conecta, $create_one);
 
 
 $create_two = "select usuario from tbl_usuarios WHERE (SUPERVISOR = TRUE AND DEPARTAMENTO = '{$departamento_usuario}') 
 OR (ADMINISTRADOR = TRUE)";
 $query_pegar_designador = mysqli_query($conecta, $create_two);
 
 
 
 $create_three = "SELECT DISTINCT COD, EMPRESAS, TRIBUTACAO FROM tbl_atividades WHERE RESPONSAVEL = '{$usuario_logado}' ORDER BY COD";
 $query_pegar_cod = mysqli_query($conecta, $create_three);
 $query_pegar_tributacao = mysqli_query($conecta, $create_three);
 
 
 $create_four = "SELECT DISTINCT COD, EMPRESAS, TRIBUTACAO FROM tbl_atividades WHERE RESPONSAVEL = '{$usuario_logado}' ORDER BY COD";
 $query_pegar_empresa = mysqli_query($conecta, $create_four);
 

 $data_de_hoje_form_atividade = date("Y-m-d");
 
 
?>
```

Sei que o PHP está desorganizado e algumas consultas são desnecessárias. Mas o problema acho que não é esse. Abaixo, mostro a imagem dos campos que eu quero que haja a interação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se puderem me ajudar, fico grato.

REFORMULANDO (Para deixar minha explicação mais sucinta. Eu gostaria de quando eu selecionar o OPTION com id = 1 de um SELECT, automaticamento o OPTION com id = 1 de um outro SELECT seja selecionado).

Consegui reduzir um pouco o código jQuery utilizado. Acho que falta bobeira para concluir.

```js
//FUNCAO PARA PRENCHER SELECT EMPRESA E TRIBUTAÇÃO DE ACORDO COM O CÓDIGO (COD) ESCOLHIDO

$(function() 
 {
 $("select#codigo-empresa").change(function(e) 
 {
  var trib = $("select#codigo-empresa option:selected").attr('name');
  $("input[id='tributacao']").val(trib);
  
  var cod = $("select#codigo-empresa option:selected").attr('id');
  $("select#empresa").val(cod);
 
 });

  
 
});


//FUNCAO PARA PRENCHER SELECT COD E TRIBUTAÇÃO DE ACORDO COM A EMPRESA ESCOLHIDA

$(function() 
 {
 $("select#empresa").change(function(e) 
 {
  var tribu = $("select#empresa option:selected").attr('name');
  $("input[id='tributacao']").val(tribu);
 
  var codigo = $("select#empresa option:selected").attr('id');
  $("select#codigo-empresa").val(codigo);
  
 });

  
 
});
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Mudar o OPTION de um SELECT de acordo com a mudança feito no outro SELECT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/363780/mudar-o-option-de-um-select-de-acordo-com-a-mudan%c3%a7a-feito-no-outro-select)

Comment: Desculpa, sou novo aqui no Stack. Poderia me explicar como faço pra oferecer recompensa ?

Comment: LipESprY, Vou apagar a outra.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90127/discussion-between-thiago-petherson-and-lipespry).

Comment: Quanto ao problema por mim relatado na pergunta, tem algo construtivo a acrescentar ?